# File Properties in Android file system

Tags: android, file, android-sdcard

I have a set of files(any document type .txt, .doc,...) in my sdcard folder. These files can be opened, edited and saved back in same location. I want to identify the Edited/Modified files from my application.

I couldn't use the File properties "created" and "last modified", when saving the file both created and the modified time are reassigned. Please suggest me a solution to find the modified files. Thanks.

Comment: FWIW, the common UNIX file APIs don't support a creation date for files -- just accessed, modified, and "changed" (the latter includes updates to file permissions as well as modifications to file data).

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the `FileObserver` feature of Android

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/FileObserver.html

You can store the events collected from `FileObserver` in a thread safe `Queue` and then access that queue whenever you want to detect changes.

Comment: I dont want to notify imediatly but I need to find only when checking.

Comment: I updated my answer, adding in the storage of ``FileObserver`` events into a  thread safe ``Queue`` so that you can access those events whenever you want to.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to calculate a checksum of file and store it. When you need to check if file is modified, just calculate checksum again and compare it with stored checksum. If checksums will be different, the file is modified.